# Asymptotic complexity comparison between two functions

Tags: time-complexity

Can anybody explain which function has a higher growth rate and why?

n<sup>1/(2*n)</sup> vs log<sub>2</sub>n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS grows faster, because LHS converges to e^(1/2n).

Explain:

if you ln-transform LHS, it becomes ln(n)/2n. By taking the limit at n ->infinity and apply L'hospital' rule, it converges to 1/2n. (I hope that I did not read your formula wrongly).